# Scala spark Matrix operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am planning to evaluate spark for machine learning algorithm implementations. Usually the algorithms I implement are expressed as matrix operations.

I've 2 questions regarding that-

1. Should algorithms be expressed as Matrix operations when implementing using Scala spark?
2. If so, does Scala/Spark have good Matrix libraries

By matrix libraries I mean  ... something as powerful as the C counterparts, BLAS, Armadillo etc.

Thanks!
Ajay

Answer (score 3):

This will be covered by the [MLbase](http://www.mlbase.org) project and the MLI API which will integrated in Spark. This is still in early stage but you can find an example of Linear Regression [here](https://github.com/amplab/MLI/blob/master/src/main/scala/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala).

Comment: nice clean API, great to see this.